# How to configure Tomcat 6 to support JSE6?

Tags: tomcat

i use the GWT framework which compiles JAVA code into Javascript. GWT can only use JSE6 jdk. For deployment i use Tomcat 6, which is only compatible with JSE5 jdk.

Any suggestions? Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have to make tomcat use sun-jdk 6. It's not correct that tomcat6 is only compatible with "JSE5 JDK",
You have multiple options how to accomplish this:
1) Download official release from Oracle http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html and set tomcat use this java as JAVA_HOME . 
Look to catalina.sh , it's up to you where you decide to define JAVA_HOME variable (just make it point to sun-jdk6 folder).
2) depends on what OS you running use package manager to install sun-jdk6 , and use system utility to set default system java :
for example in Ubuntu/Debian it would be :

```
1) Add /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
Update packages list:
aptitude update
2) Install:
aptitude install sun-java6-jdk
3) Set default JVM :
 sudo update-alternatives --config java
```